# How to allow sorting in the Django admin by a custom list_display field, which doesn't have a DB field nor annotatable

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a custom list_display field which is responsible for a column of integers in one of my admin pages.

I need to allow staff members to sort according to it.

There's a solution for how to acheive that if the integer represents a count/average/etc of some DB field, which is not the case for me.

[ the solution for that case is here: [Django admin: how to sort by one of the custom list_display fields that has no database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-da)
]

Any ideas how I can achieve this sorting without actually creating and maintaining a DB field for the values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3351431/17498

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sorting is done at the DB Engine (in an order by clause), so I don't think you will be able to achieve what you want unless you materialize a field in the model. Computed states are not sortable at this point (at least not in the admin interface, if you were using your own interface you could use [extra](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none)).

If the problem were filtering, you could write a custom FilterSpec (which doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but SO has a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin)).

But for sorting in the admin your only option is a materialized field, I'm afraid.

**Edit:**

Hmmm...

You could try something. [It is possible](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/) (albeit I don't think it is documented anywhere formally) to change the queryset used by a ModelAdmin. If your computed field is simple enough to be embedded in the query itself you could do something like:

```
class BlahAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ... Whatever definitions ...

    def queryset(self, request):
        return Blah.objects.extra(select={'computed': "count(field_x)"})
```

This might work. It is untested though.

Comment: if your object is Proxied, you have to add an ordering to the proxy meta class: ordering=['computed',], otherwise it'll use 'id' for some reason.