# Django count today's logged in users

Tags: django, django-admin, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I want to show on my admin interface the count of the users those did log in today. My admin interface looks like following:

[image]

When I print from my view

```
 count = User.objects.filter(last_login=timezone.now()).count()
```

it gives me 0 as both the date/time format are different. i.e. 2016-06-01 14:58:29.079000+00:00

**How can I get that count on my admin interface somewhere?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the date from the timezone.now() and then use filter 'startswith' to filter by date:

```
count = User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()
```

In addition to add this column to your Django Admin Interface you can check this [Custom columns using Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164610/custom-columns-using-django-admin)

Comment: Yes the first answer solves my problem. Second answer is also correct, however what I want is bit different, not just adding a column but customizing widget. take a look here, if you would like to answer separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579348/django-show-object-count-on-admin-interface

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
count = User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()
```