# Django show object count on admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-rest-framework

I have modified my dashboard with the help of dashboard.py file. There in I have added a custom module/widget called 'My Widget' (haven't created myself but rather just appended as a child referring to a specific django app). Code is as follows:

```
  # append an app list module for "Administration"
    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('Administration'),
        models=('django.contrib.*',),
    ))

    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('My widget'),
        models=('flights.*',),
        children=[

        ]
    ))
```

flights is my django app which has three models. Dashboard looks like following:[image]

On this widget I want to show the count of users who did log in today.
The count itself I was able to get (not on admin interface but through a view accessible via url for testing purpose) with following code snippet:
 `User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()`

**How can I show such a count on this widget?**

The entire dashboard.py:

```
"""
This file was generated with the customdashboard management command, it
contains the two classes for the main dashboard and app index dashboard.
You can customize these classes as you want.

To activate your index dashboard add the following to your settings.py::
ADMIN_TOOLS_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'api.dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard'

And to activate the app index dashboard::
ADMIN_TOOLS_APP_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'api.dashboard.CustomAppIndexDashboard'
"""

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from admin_tools.dashboard import modules, Dashboard, AppIndexDashboard
from admin_tools.utils import get_admin_site_name
from admin_tools_stats.modules import DashboardCharts, get_active_graph

class CustomIndexDashboard(Dashboard):
 """
Custom index dashboard for api.
"""
columns = 3

def init_with_context(self, context):
    site_name = get_admin_site_name(context)
    # append a link list module for "quick links"
    self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
        _('Quick links'),
        layout='inline',
        draggable=False,
        deletable=False,
        collapsible=False,
        children=[
            [_('Return to site'), '/'],
            [_('Change password'),
             reverse('%s:password_change' % site_name)],
            [_('Log out'), reverse('%s:logout' % site_name)],
        ]
    ))

    graph_list = get_active_graph()
    for i in graph_list:
        kwargs = {}
        kwargs['require_chart_jscss'] = True
        kwargs['graph_key'] = i.graph_key

        if context['request'].POST.get('select_box_' + i.graph_key):
            kwargs['select_box_' + i.graph_key] =   context['request'].POST['select_box_' + i.graph_key]
            self.children.append(DashboardCharts(**kwargs))

    # append an app list module for "Applications"
    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('All Applications'),
        exclude=('django.contrib.*',),
    ))

    # append an app list module
    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('Dashboard Stats Settings'),
        models=('admin_tools_stats.*', ),
    ))

    # append an app list module for "Administration"
    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('Administration'),
        models=('django.contrib.*',),
    ))

    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('My widget'),
        models=('flights.*',),
        content='test content',
        children=[

        ]
    ))

    # append a recent actions module
    self.children.append(modules.RecentActions(_('Recent Actions'), 4))        


    # append another link list module for "support".
    self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
        _('Support'),
        children=[
            {
                'title': _('Django documentation'),
                'url': 'http://docs.djangoproject.com/',
                'external': True,
            },
            {
                'title': _('Django "django-users" mailing list'),
                'url': 'http://groups.google.com/group/django-users',
                'external': True,
            },
            {
                'title': _('Django irc channel'),
                'url': 'irc://irc.freenode.net/django',
                'external': True,
            },
        ]
    ))




class CustomAppIndexDashboard(AppIndexDashboard):
"""
Custom app index dashboard for api.
"""

# we disable title because its redundant with the model list module
title = ''

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    AppIndexDashboard.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # append a model list module and a recent actions module
    self.children += [
        modules.ModelList(self.app_title, self.models),
        modules.RecentActions(
            _('Recent Actions'),
            include_list=self.get_app_content_types(),
            limit=5
        )
    ]

def init_with_context(self, context):
    """
    Use this method if you need to access the request context.
    """
    return super(CustomAppIndexDashboard, self).init_with_context(context)
```

Comment: and what is your dashboard.py?

Comment: Updated question with complete dashboard.py

Comment: Have you found the answer?