# Get data in model methods from multiple models - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm quite new to Django (Python too) and learning it by doing.

I'm playing with Django admin site. I've created two models and successfully registered in admin. The data is nicely displayed for the fields given in `list_display`.
I want an another table in admin, which displays data from both the tables by processing with some logic.

To get the another table based on the previous two models data, I can create a new model with only methods as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164610/custom-columns-using-django-admin).

Now the problem is that, how can I get data from other model tables and how to return, so that it can be displayed in table in admin.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class GoodsItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    INCHES = 'IN'
    NUMBER = 'NUM'
    GOODS_ITEM_SIZE_UNITS = (
        (INCHES, 'Inches'),
        (NUMBER, '#'),
    )
    size_unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=GOODS_ITEM_SIZE_UNITS,
        default=INCHES,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        if(self.size_unit == self.NUMBER):
            return "%s #%s" % (self.name, (self.size).normalize())
        else:
            return "%s %s\"" % (self.name, (self.size).normalize())


class FinishedGoodsItem(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    goods_item = models.ForeignKey(GoodsItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="finished_name")
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.goods_item)


class SoldGoodsItem(models.Model):
    goods_item = models.ForeignKey(GoodsItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sold_name")
    date = models.DateField()
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.goods_item
```

The third table in admin should show data like:

```
===============================
GoodsItem   |   Stock Available
===============================
```

Here GoodsItem is string representation of GoodsItem model and Stock available should be calculated as:

Sum of weight in FinishedGoodsItem for particular GoodsItem till last entry(i.e. last date of entry) - Sum of weight in SoldGoodsItem for particular GoodsItem till last entry(i.e. last date of entry)

I will implement the logic, if some kind personality tell me how to query data and return by different methods in model. If in any doubt, feel free to ask.

Comment: Nothing in that linked question talks about creating a separate model. But you don't need to; you can get the set of Sold and FinishedGoodsItems via the `related_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want one row per `GoodsItem` object. You can add the "stock available" column directly to the `GoodsItem` admin without creating a separate model, as Daniel Roseman says.

Example code (might not be 100% correct, but you get the point):

```
class GoodsItem(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def stock_available(self):
        stock_finished = self.finished_name.aggregate(Sum('weight'))['weight__sum']
        stock_sold = self.sold_name.aggregate(Sum('weight'))[
            'weight__sum']
        return stock_finished - stock_sold


class GoodsItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('name', 'size', 'size_unit', 'stock_available')
```

See the [Django docs on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/). Keep in mind that this will perform two extra queries per item shown in the list.

---

***EDIT:*** The solution proposed below doesn't work due to the Django bug with aggregations and multiple tables described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations), as highlighted in a comment. Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598245/multiple-annotate-with-sum-and-display-data-in-admin-django) that uses subqueries instead.

Another option if the previous solution was too slow due to many queries:

```
class GoodsItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'size', 'size_unit', 'stock_available')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(GoodsItemAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(stock_available=Sum('finished_name__weight') - Sum('sold_name__weight'))
        return qs
```

Note that this last option only adds the feature to the admin, but that might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you just explain that here `finished_name` and `sold_name` is referring to what? As I stated earlier I'm new to both Python and Django, so this might be a dumb question.

Comment: `finished_name` and `sold_name` are the backref names you specified in your model definitions in the arguments `related_name`.

Comment: As I can see, `finished_name` and `sold_name` are not the members of `GoodsItem` class, then how can we access them like `self.finished_name` in `stock_available` method of `GoodsItem`?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: While I used second example code provided by you, I'm getting incorrect `stock_available`, why?

Comment: As multiple table annotation has [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060). We can use Subquery as mentioned in my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598245/multiple-annotate-with-sum-and-display-data-in-admin-django).