# Django update number of items on each save or delete

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and still learning. I am looking to keep track of how many `events` I have under a test. My current model looks like

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    num_of_events = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Test'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tests'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self):
        obj, created = Test.objects.update_or_create(name=self.test)
        obj.num_of_events += 1
        super().save()

    def delete(self):
        self.test.num_of_events -= 1
        super().delete()
```

I thought I could just override the `save()` function but it does not update on the admin panel and still shows 0.

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: admin.py

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'num_of_events')

    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'description')})
    ]

class EventsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'property_type', 'expected_value')

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
admin.site.register(Event, EventsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Property, PropertyAdmin)
```

Comment: Please don't store the number of items. You can use annotate to fetch the number of `Event`s per `Test`. This is more reliable.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is *not* saving the `Test` object, but regardless, *data duplication* is *not* a good idea.

Comment: annotation/aggregation docs -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

You forget to save the `Test` object. For example with:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # …

    def save(self):
        if self.test_id is not None:
            obj = self.test
            obj.num_of_events += 1
            obj.save()
        super().save()

    def delete(self):
        if self.test_id is not None:
            self.test.num_of_events -= 1
            self.test.save()
        super().delete()
```

But regardless, storing the number of items is usually *not* a good idea. Say that you change the `.test` of a given `Event`, then you need to subtract from the old `Test` and add to the new `Test`. Furthermore ORM operations in bulk, like `.update(..)` *circumvent* `.save()` and signals, so it will be hard or impossible to keep this correct.

The point is that you **do *not* need** to store the number of `Event`s. Indeed, you can simply obtain these with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Test.objects.annotate(number_of_events=Count('event'))
```

The `Test` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.number_of_events` that contains the number of related `Event` ojbects.

Comment: Where would I put that line at?

Comment: @Halloween: in the views where you for example need the number of events, or need to filter on the number of events.

Comment: It is in the admin page. I am using list_display to print out the variables in the panel.

Comment: @Halloween: you can override the `get_queryset` of the `ModelAdmin` to show annotations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48607830/67579

Comment: I added my admin.py to the question. Would I be putting it in the EventsAdmin function?

Comment: @Halloween: no, in the `TestAdmin`, since that is the one with the number of events.

Comment: Is there anywhere that explains this? i am not understanding it.