# Is there a way to concatenate 2 model field names in the "list display" to display as one column in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the Django Admin area, rather than have two separate columns for `first_name` and `last_name` to display, I'd like to concatenate those to create one column.

I want to avoid creating a separate model field to get this done.
One solution could be to return `self`, but that seems to not work either.

The code below gets me "This site cannot be reached."

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Agent

class RealtorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('MLS_number', 'first_name' + 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'hire_Date')
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164610/custom-columns-using-django-admin) for more examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either define it as a property or method on the model, as PRMoureu showed, or define it directly on the ModelAdmin class:

```
class RealtorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('MLS_number', 'full_name', 'email', 'phone', 'hire_Date')

  def full_name(self, obj):
    return '{} {}'.format(obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

This is better if the admin is the only place you'll use this; otherwise the model is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a property in the model :

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
        # return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'  # with python 3.6+
```

And then call it in the fields :

```
class RealtorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('MLS_number', 'fullname', 'email', 'phone', 'hire_Date')
```

Comment: @CalebGoodman, yep it's a clear and usefull syntax, but sadly not available in every versions of python. Thanks for the suggestion ;-)

Comment: YW.  I'm just a bit tilted that you beat me to the answer :)

Comment: @CalebGoodman Many answers is not a bad thing if each one brings something (even slightly) different