# Django admin: how to sort column by custom method

Tags: django, django-admin

```
 class Item(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

     def admin_amount(self):
         total = self.warehouse_set.all().aggregate(item=Sum('amount'))
         return total['item']

 class Warehouse(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     item = models.ForeignKey('Item', blank=True, null=True)
     amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Create new field is wrong, but I cant do something like:

```
 admin_amount.admin_order_field = 'admin_amount'
```

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d) but I encountered a problem with rewriting queryset() method(can't write something like `qs.warehouse_set.all().annotate(models.Sum('amount'))`). Is there any way to adapt this solution for me or in my case, there is another solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using the code in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d) (and the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/468872)), the bottom should do it for your example. The principle is to use annotate to add additional data from a sub-query to the returned QuerySet. In this case the `Sum` of the amounts in warehouses.

Next you add a wrapper function `amount_in_warehouses` to get this value out for each row, and tell the admin to show this for listing `list_display = ('amount_in_warehouses',)`, and sort on it `amount_in_warehouses.admin_order_field = 'amount_in_warehouses'`.

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('amount_in_warehouses',)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ItemAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(models.Sum('warehouse__amount'))
        return qs

    def amount_in_warehouses(self, obj):
        return obj.warehouse__amount__sum
    amount_in_warehouses.admin_order_field = 'amount_in_warehouses'
```