# Ordering list_display fields by a filter on a related model

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm having an issue where I want to sort based on the aggregate of a related field in the admin and not sure of the best way to go about it.  Here are my models:

```
# models.py   
from django.db import models

class Waiter(models.Model):
    pass

class Customer(models.Model):
    pass

class Meal(models.Model):
    BREAKFAST = 1
    LUNCH = 2
    DINNER = 3
    MEAL_TYPE_CHOICES = (
            (BREAKFAST, 'Breakfast'),
            (LUNCH, 'Lunch'),
            (DINNER, 'Dinner'),
            )
    meal_type = models.IntegerField(choices=MEAL_TYPE_CHOICES)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    waiter = models.ForeignKey(Waiter)
    service_rating = models.IntegerField()
```

In the waiter admin, I want to display the average service rating for each waiter for breakfast, lunch and dinner and want to be able to order by each of these as a separate column.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d) explained how to order by the average of all  service ratings for each waiter (code below), but I'd really like to order by the appropriate service ratings for each meal type.  What would be the best way to do this?

```
# admin.py
from .models import Customer, Meal, Waiter

from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Avg

class WaiterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display('avg_breakfast_rating', 'avg_lunch_rating', 'avg_dinner_rating')

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(WaiterAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(Avg('meal__service_rating'))
        return qs

    def avg_breakfast_rating(self, obj):
        breakfasts = Meal.objects.filter(waiter=obj, meal_type=Meal.BREAKFAST)
        return breakfasts.aggregate(avg_rating=Avg('service_rating'))['avg_rating']
    avg_breakfast_rating.short_description = 'Average Breakfast Rating'
    avg_breakfast_rating.admin_order_field = 'meal__service_rating__avg'

    def avg_lunch_rating(self, obj):
        lunches = Meal.objects.filter(waiter=obj, meal_type=Meal.LUNCH)
        return lunches.aggregate(avg_rating=Avg('service_rating'))['avg_rating']
    avg_lunch_rating.short_description = 'Average Lunch Rating'
    avg_lunch_rating.admin_order_field = 'meal__service_rating__avg'

    def avg_dinner_rating(self, obj):
        dinners = Meal.objects.filter(waiter=obj, meal_type=Meal.DINNER)
        return dinners.aggregate(avg_rating=Avg('service_rating'))['avg_rating']
    avg_dinner_rating.short_description = 'Average Dinner Rating'
    avg_dinner_rating.admin_order_field = 'meal__service_rating__avg'
```

Basically, instead of having the admin_order_field be `meal__service_rating__avg`, I want to have something like `breakfast__service_rating__avg`, `lunch__service_rating__avg` and `dinner__service_rating__avg` to order on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this purely with the ORM (at least, I couldn't find a way).  However, there is a somewhat straightforward solution if you are willing to use extra() and some custom SQL.

Specifics may vary based on database, but this appears to work with sqlite3:

```
class WaiterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'breakfast_avg', 'lunch_avg', 'dinner_avg')

    def _avg_query(self, meal_type):
        return """
               SELECT AVG(service_rating) FROM {meal_table}
               WHERE meal_type={meal_type} AND waiter_id={waiter_table}.id
               """.format(meal_table=Meal._meta.db_table,
                          waiter_table=Waiter._meta.db_table,
                          meal_type=meal_type)


    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(WaiterAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.extra({'breakfast_avg': self._avg_query(Meal.BREAKFAST),
                       'lunch_avg': self._avg_query(Meal.LUNCH),
                       'dinner_avg': self._avg_query(Meal.DINNER),
                      })
        return qs

    def breakfast_avg(self, obj):
        return obj.breakfast_avg
    breakfast_avg.short_description = 'Average Breakfast Rating'
    breakfast_avg.admin_order_field = 'breakfast_avg'

    def lunch_avg(self, obj):
        return obj.lunch_avg
    lunch_avg.short_description = 'Average Lunch Rating'
    lunch_avg.admin_order_field = 'lunch_avg'

    def dinner_avg(self, obj):
        return obj.dinner_avg
    dinner_avg.short_description = 'Average Dinner Rating'
    dinner_avg.admin_order_field = 'dinner_avg'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I usually use postgres, so I'll adjust the syntax and try this.  Am traveling at the moment so may have to test when I get back.

Answer (score 2):

I would add these fields to Waiter:

```
breakfast_service_rating_avg = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
lunch_service_rating_avg = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
dinner_service_rating_avg = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Then the save() method of Meal would call the save() method of the Waiter instance where you calculate the three averages for *_service_rating_avg before saving the Waiter instance.

Then you always have the average on the waiter instance and you can comfortably sort in the admin. Also to annotate is quite an expensive operation, I'd avoid it if possible and provide for the mentioned additional fields.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: This is a great suggestion!  The other answer fit more closely with what I was trying to do without adding additional fields to the database.  I'm not sure how expensive annotate actually is.  I'm pretty sure all the work is done in the db so it should be fast relative to doing something in Python, though slower than a simpler database operation.  I'll see if I can run some benchmarks to get some data.