# Django admin: Custom ordering

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filter

I have version field for a model, a string field. I defined my Django admin ordering by that field ("-version"). 
The problem is python's version comparison doesn't work when it comes to strings. For example:

```
vers=['5.10.0.','5.9.0','5.8.0']
vers[0]>vers[1]
>>False
```

Should be **true**. 
How do I write custom ordering without changing the models?
I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d), but it works only for aggregation functions.

Note: I need solution for **ordering**, not **list_filter**, which I already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d). I changed the lookup as follows:

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    qs = model_admin.queryset(request)
    vers = qs.values_list('version', flat=True).distinct().order_by('-version')
    s_vers = [tuple([int(x) for x in n.split('.')]) for n in vers]
    s_vers = sorted(s_vers, reverse=True)
    ns_vers = ['.'.join(map(str, x)) for x in s_vers]
    ret_vers = []

    for v in ns_vers:
        ret_vers.append((v, v))

    return ret_vers
```

Comment: I don't think this would be possible in django admin. The ordering depends upon the model fields, and standard comparison between their values. ordering can't be applied using such complex comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.extra(select={'nversion': "string_to_array(version, '.')::bigint[]"}).order_by('-nversion')
        return qs

    def vers(self, obj):
        return obj.nversion

    ordering = ('-nversion',)
```