# Django admin: SORTING list_display field from reverse FK aggregation

Tags: python, django

The model *Station* has a FK to *System*. I want to display *Station* count as a column in the *System* admin change list. I have achieved this with the code below but I am having difficulty making the 'num_stations' column sortable.

model.py:

```
class System(models.Model):
    pass

class Station(models.Model):
   system_info = models.ForeignKey(System)
```

admin.py:

```
class SystemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def num_stations(self, obj):
        return obj.station_set.count()

    # num_stations.admin_order_field = ????
    num_stations.short_description = 'stations'

    list_display = (num_stations',)
```

The ordinary 'station_set' syntax for a reverse relationship doesn't seem to work in the admin_order_field, even though other stack overflow question commonly show traversing a relation in the forward direction is supported 
e.g.

- [Django admin: how to sort by one of the custom list_display fields that has no database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d)
- [Can “list_display” in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field).

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d) that you linked to contains the answer. You need to override the queryset and annotate the count. It isn't possible to use `admin_order_field` to reference `station_set.count()`, and even if it was, it would be less efficient to do a count for every item in the queryset instead of the annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) for their comment, the answer was in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d) as pointed out. Here is the solution that fits my problem:

```
class SystemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def num_stations(self, obj):
        return obj.num_stations

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # def queryset(self, request): # For Django <1.6
        qs = super(SystemAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        # qs = super(CustomerAdmin, self).queryset(request) # For Django <1.6
        qs = qs.annotate(num_stations=Count('station'))
        return qs

    num_stations.admin_order_field = 'num_stations'
    num_stations.short_description = 'stations'

    list_display = ('num_stations', )
```