# Django Rest. Ordering by calculated model field

Tags: django, sorting, django-rest-framework

I am stuck with ordering on calculated field.

Let's say my model looks like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.CharField()
    fieldB = models.CharField()

    @property
    def calculatedField(self):
        return someFunc(fieldA)
```

Now I wan't my `ViewSet` to be able to apply ordering to `calculatedField`, so I have following code in there:

```
class SomeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    ...
    ordering_fields = ('calculatedField',)
    ...
```

But when I try to apply to order using query parameters like

```
Method GET /someEndpoint/?ordering=calculatedField
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'calculatedField' into the field. Choices are: ...
```

Is there a way to apply to order to calculatedField? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168475/django-admin-how-to-sort-by-one-of-the-custom-list-display-fields-that-has-no-d

Answer (score 0):

you have to annotate the extra field

```
class SomeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
...
ordering_fields = ('calculatedField',)

def get_queryset(self):
   return self.queryset.annotate(other function)
```

Comment: I have  tried like this: ```self.queryset.annotate(other_function(F('one_of_the_fields_on_model')))```, but it turned out exceptions cause ```F('one_of_the_fields_on_model')``` is not an actual value. How should I do?

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all.